# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' in random.py in py3.7

Tags: python

```
 result = [None] * k
 setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list
 if k > 5:
```

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: We will have to see how you're calling into `random` too.

Answer (score 1):

If this line is producing the error then it's obvious.

k is a float and you can't multiply a list with a float. So, if you cast your float k to int, the code runs without error.

```
 k = int(k)
 result = [None] * k
 setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list
 if k > 5:
```

[image]

Comment: I assumed that `random.py` was Pythons `random.py` and changing that wouldn't be the best of ideas. If the OP called his own file `random.py` your answer will help, but I'd strongly suggest not to use this file name.

Comment: Instead of saying "it's obvious", it may be helpful to the asker if you give some kind of explanation about what's going on here

Comment: Don't think it's the python random module, no reason to edit that. I agree, random.py is a very bad choice, it can mess up the namespace.

Comment: I think I provided two examples to show the contrast.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot multiply a list by a float type and it seems like 'k' is a float type. Try converting to int type before.

```
result = [None] * int(k)
setsize = 21
if k > 5:
```